# Layer separation before Z seam on VoxeLab Aquila

Tags: pla

I purchased new PLA, and from the first print, the wall layers will have little gaps in them but only "just before" (depending on the size this can be half an inch to a couple of inches) the Z seam. I thought it was a new PLA problem, nope, did a temperature tower and different shape prints, flawless.

It seems to be only my models that I make in Fusion 360 (I haven't tried downloading other people's models to see what happens) and slice in Cura that mess up. I even printed my piece, with the Cura cylinder preset shapes. My piece had defects, the shape came out perfect. I put a picture of the Cone that was messed up.

I have a VoxeLab Aquila which I use together with Ultimaker Cura. I print in PLA at 210 °C. Bed temperature is 60 °C. I use a print cooling fan at 100 %. The layer height I set to 0.3 mm, the line width 0.4 from the 0.4 mm nozzle. The Printing Speed is set to 30 mm/s for walls and 50 mm/s for infill. My retraction is 4 mm/off at 35 mm/s.

[image: Photo of a printed model with printing errors]

Comment: Check that you do not have "coasting" enabled in your Cura configuration. I'm not sure where you got the profile for your printer, but at least a few of the printer profiles that ship with Cura have this (very harmful) misfeature enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Check the STL file once you have exported from fusion360, sometimes stl files from fusion360 needs to be watertight one. In this case, yes, some models might leave a gap.
2. Check if nozzle is clean, sometimes partial clog can cause this issue too.